# Sql increment particular column from 1 to N

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I have the column named UID , which current data is like below

```
uid
---
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I want to fill the value from 1 to N. So for example below

```
uid
---
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
.
.
n
```

How can i loop through all row and increment values.

Comment: is it the primary key ? if yes just make it autoincrement in phpmaydmin

Comment: `alter table table_name modify column uid int(4) auto_increment`

Comment: I tried , i get Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: please confirm that uid primary key or not if it is primary key then put it autoincrement

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi : I get  Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Leave every thing and follow this video from the beginning http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcl9b8BtvpE

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar : i am unable to make that column primary...i get Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only define a column as AUTO_INCREMENT if it is a PRIMARY KEY and an INT !
Since you want the UID to be set as AUTO_INCREMENT, why not make it as PRIMARY KEY

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
(
    UID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -- other columns...
)
```

Comment: problem is i am unable to make it primary

Comment: try this ``ALTER TABLE `'TableName'` MODIFY COLUMN `'uid'` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;``
`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table
ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid) AUTOINCREMENT;`

Comment: ncorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 50;   //number of your records suppose it was 50 
for($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
    $res =  mysql_query("select * from `table name` where `UID`=0 LIMIT 1 ");
    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {

        mysql_query("update `table name` set `UID`='$i' where UID=0 limit 1   ") or die(mysql_error)  

    }
}
```

Comment: cant we do without php ?

Comment: unable to make it primary bcoz primary key value must be unique and uid value is 0 in all row, first change it after u are  able to make this field of primary key

Comment: hey you said to use to "unique value ex id is unique then write where id='$id'" ... but i dont have any unique column

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way just to display a sequence rows as following:

```
SET @rank=0;
select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank from Table1;
```

Otherwise do it with `PHP`

**EDIT**

Try to do something like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE Table1 MODIFY COLUMN `id` int(4) Primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: should i rename AS rank from to AS uid from ?

Comment: hey querry is successfull , but its not reflecting in main table ??

Comment: @user3305305 yeah, and you will get the same result.

Comment: yea i got the result like uid 1 2 3 4 5 ..but its not reflecting in my table ?

Comment: @user3305305 thats why i told you `just to display`